# How to do the equivalent of eval-last-sexp on Clojure code

Tags: emacs, clojure, synchronization, read-eval-print-loop

**EDIT** For a reason which I haven't fully understood yet my C-x C-e was bound to *eval-last-sexp* and instead of (?) *slime-eval-last-expression*.  Now I can *C-x C-e* from the *.clj* buffer and I can at least see directly when my function is (in)correct but, however, this apparently doesn't make the function I just *slime-eval-last-expression* "available" to the REPL.

I've set up my Emacs to do some Clojure programming and I don't know if my setup is correct or not.

I've got two buffers: one for the *.clj* file and one for the REPL. I'm using *clojure-jack-in* to start the REPL.

Apparently I need to always compile the *.clj* (which *also* always forces me to save the file with a prompt) and I then need to switch to the REPL and issue a *(use 'myname.space)* in the REPL before being able to try, say, a new function I wrote.

This is a lot of keys to press for what seems like a very simple thing.

Now, of course, I could write an Emacs macro doing the whole *save / confirm / switch to REPL / issue (use 'myname.space)* shebang but I was wondering if my setup was correct or not?

I guess that my question in other words would be: is the REPL I'm connected to supposed to always be "in synch" with the buffer containing the *.clj* I'm working on or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using Slime if you're editing clojure with Emacs. See https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure

Then, when you've used M-x clojure-jack-in to start and connect a REPL in emacs, you can just do C-x C-e to compile and load the current sexp, or C-x C-k to compile and load the current buffer.

In other words, your repl is not "automatically" in sync with whatever you've just typed in some clojure code buffer, but there are much quicker and easier ways to send code from a buffer to the running clojure program.

Comment: but I'm using *clojure-jack-in*... If I ask what C-x C-e is bound to it says *eval-last-sexp* and it's apparently trying to eval the code as if it was elisp code (?).  In other words: everytime I try to *eval-last-sexp* from the buffer I get an exception.  Same file compiles fine using C-c C-k and same functions work fine in the REPL (either using cut/paste or by calling *use*).  What is the name of the function *C-x C-e* should run?  *eval-last-sexp* ?

Comment: I think a first problem was that my C-x C-e was bound to *eval-last-sexp* instead of *slime-eval-last-expression*.  Not 100% sure about this entire issue that said.